# Deploying Angular Frontend with NodeJS/Express Backend with Docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, express, nginx

I have developed a web application using Angular for the frontend and NodeJS/Express for the backend. Everything is running fine locally and I would like to move the application to Docker containers. Now unfortunately the following problem arises:

I use a cookie which holds my session token. Locally this works without problems, but as soon as I try the whole thing with the containers, the whole thing doesn't work anymore.

When I try to log in I can see in the network analysis of my browser that the cookie is sent from the backend (the session token). Unfortunately, the browser does not save this. Even if I add the cookie manually, the cookie is not sent back to the backend for authorization.

here are some code snippets to understand what i did:

Frontend:

```
  public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<ResponseMessage> {
    const loginObservable = this.http.post<ResponseMessage>(this.server + '/api/login', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).pipe(shareReplay());
    loginObservable.subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
      },
      error: () => {
        this.loggedIn = false;
      }
    });
    return loginObservable;
  }
```

Backend (the part that generates the cookie):

```
private async generateSession(user:User, response:Response): Promise<void>{
      try{
        const sessionId = uid.sync(24);
        await user.createSession({sessionId: sessionId});
        response.cookie('sessionId', sessionId, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 });
        return;
      }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
```

When I already have a session token, its checked by this code in the backend:

```
public async authorize(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
      try{
        const sessionId = request.cookies.sessionId;
        console.log(request.cookies.sessionId);        //<-- This prints undefined when using Docker
        if (!sessionId) return next();
        const session:Session = await Session.findOne({
          where: {
            sessionId: sessionId
          },
        });
        if (!session) return next();
        response.locals.session = session;
        // Überprüfen ob ein User zur Session existiert
        const user:User = await session.getUser();
        if (!user) return next();
        response.locals.user = user;
        return next();
      }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
      }


    }
```

when opening the url for authorization directly in the browser (localhost:3000/api/auth) it gives back true (as long as i have the cookie) but it gives back false when my frontend inside a docker container asks.

What am i overseeing?

I tried some stuff with the NGINX config file.

```
# CORS settings
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'localhost';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Credentials';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
```

this didn't help unfortunately.

Edit:

This is what the frontend gets back from the backend:

[link to the screenshot of the browser-networkanalysis window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkytU.png)

Comment: Are you adding `withCredentials` to your requests, preferably in an interceptor, in Angular?

Comment: @brandon-taylor I just tried but it sadly didn't solve the problem. What kind of information could i further supply to make it easier to solve this issue?

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure. Running in a container shouldn't have any effect on your app's ability to send a cookie to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the problem, but via a different route. My solution to my problem is now that I have the frontend hosted by the backend (nodejs/express now hosts the compiled frontend). This solved the problem, but the front and backend are running in the same docker container.